# EWS using OAUth (app only) for multiple tenants throwing Access is denied /401 unauthorised on EmailMessage.Bind()

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

I have registered an application for OAuth with Azure and Exchange 365 permission (full-access-as-app).

When I try to access EmailMessage.Bind(service, fixedId, propertySet) from my web app it throws this error .

Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again., The process failed to get the correct properties.

Tried giving explicit permissions as well (calender ,contact ,emailsettings ) with all admin consented .

Albeit I am able to send email and create tasks.

Any thing I am missing ? I would appreciate any help.

Thanks ,
AK

Update :

I am using following code and application registration ( app-only )following this :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

I have 2 tenants A and B ,accounts from tenant A where application is registered are fine but from tenant B it fails with this error : The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it.

Consent and permissions for both tenants are set as :
Allow user consent for apps

Property sets are created like this :

```
    var propertySet = new 
    PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
                {
                    var extendedPropertyDefinition = new 
    ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, 
   propertyName, MapiPropertyType.String);
                    propertySet.Add(extendedPropertyDefinition);
                }
                else
                {
                    propertySet.Add(new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, PersonIdPropertyName, MapiPropertyType.String));
                    propertySet.Add(new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, PersonDataPropertyName, MapiPropertyType.String));
                    propertySet.Add(new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, PersonContextPropertyName, MapiPropertyType.String));
                }
```

Comment: What does your code look like are you using Impersonation?

Comment: Why are using a Service Account ? if your using the client Credentials flow then you don't need an account the Service Principal authenticates using a Client Secret (or Certificate) then you should impersonate the account of the Mailbox your trying to access. The service account is basically redundant, it might help if you show your auth and EWS code as it sounds like you may be mixing authentication modes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please see the updated notes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question .

**Issue 1:** "Unauthorized 401 errors" are due to when admin consent is not granted in consumer tenant directory .

**Issue 2:** "The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it" were due to OAuth registered in different tenant (in case of multi tenant )

If Auth app is served by multiple tenants then you need to take care of two things :

**1:** supported account should be : Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox) while registering auth app.

**2:** Build application builder with
'''
var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
.Create(appId)
.WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id of consumer}")
.WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
.Build();

instead of

var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
.Create(appId)
.WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
.WithTenantId(tenantId)
.Build();

**For Example:**

If auth app is registered in A ,and you want to authenticate office365 accounts in tenant B ,then admin in tenant B should grant admin consent to app using this link [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tennatid](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btennatid) of tenant B}/adminconsent?client_id={clientid of auth app}
and use authority as "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id tenant B} while creating application builder.

'''